# Name of k-nearest-neighbor prototype selection method iteratively adding examples

Tags: terminology, k-nearest-neighbour

I've been trying out a prototype selection method for 1-nearest-neighbor classification, but I don't really know what to search for to find literature/papers about the method:

1. Initialize the prototype set with one training example from every class (e.g. randomly selected or the class centroid or something else)
2. For every training example, determine the training error rate when that example is added to the prototype set and add the example with the lowest error rate to the prototype set.
3. Repeat step 2 until some stopping criterion is met.

Answer (score 1):

The first step toward prototype learning involves the algorithm known as Learning Vector Quantization ([LVQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_vector_quantization)), which involves neurons.  In this case, a single neuron is a "prototype," which is merely a learning vector whose dimensions is the same as the number of input features you have.  kNN is used as an internal in a lot of methods, so you would need to search for exactly what you want -- which may not exist.